# Plot and process ggplot2 object in same expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, magrittr

I would like to build up my GGplot graph and plot the steps in between. Is this possible to do without first assigning and then plotting?

```
p0 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()
p0
p1 <- p0 + scale_x_sqrt()
p1
p2 <- p1 + facet_wrap(~gear)
p2
```

Something like

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point() %P>%
 + scale_x_sqrt() %P>%
 + facet_wrap(~gear)
```

Which produces three plots but returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing!

```
`%P+%` <- function(p1, p2) {p <- ggplot2:::`+.gg`(p1, p2); print(p); invisible(p)}
```

And the call

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) %P+% 
  geom_point() %P+%
  scale_x_sqrt() %P+%
  facet_wrap(~gear)
```

will get you three plots in a row. The only limitation is that you have to be careful around mixing regular `+` and `%P+%` because of precedence issues.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to force evaluation at every step rather than wait to the end of the pipeline?

Comment: You are welcome! Well, I added `Sys.sleep` and I do see immediate evaluation for each step, maybe I musinderstood the question.